# Given primary key, compare other columns of two data frames and output diff columns in the vertical way

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to compare two dataframes that have the same schema, and have a primary key column.

For each primary key, if other columns have any difference (could be multiple columns, so need to use some dynamic way to scan all other columns), I want to output the column name and values of both dataframes.

Also, I want to output the result if one primary key doesn't exist in another dataframe (so "full outer join" will be used). Here is some example:

dataframe1:

```
+-----------+------+------+
|primary_key|book  |number|
+-----------+------+------+
|1          |book1 | 1    | 
|2          |book2 | 2    |
|3          |book3 | 3    |
|4          |book4 | 4    |
+-----------+------+------+
```

dataframe2:

```
+-----------+------+------+
|primary_key|book  |number|
+-----------+------+------+
|1          |book1 | 1    | 
|2          |book8 | 8    |
|3          |book3 | 7    |
|5          |book5 | 5    |
+-----------+------+------+
```

The result would be:

```
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------*
|primary_key|diff_column_name | dataframe1 | dataframe2 |
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------*
|2          |book             | book2      | book8      |
|2          |number           | 2          | 8          |
|3          |number           | 3          | 7          |
|4          |book             | book4      | null       |
|4          |number           | 4          | null       |
|5          |book             | null       | book5      |
|5          |number           | null       | 5          |
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------*
```

I know the first step is to join both dataframes on the primary key:

```scala
// joining the two DFs on primary_key
val result = df1.as("l")
    .join(df2.as("r"), "primary_key", "fullouter")
```

But I am not sure how to proceed. Can someone give me some advice? Thanks

Comment: What if more than one column has a different value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data:

```scala
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "book1", 1), (2, "book2", 2), (3, "book3", 3), (4, "book4", 4)
).toDF("primary_key", "book", "number")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "book1", 1), (2, "book8", 8), (3, "book3", 7), (5, "book5", 5)
).toDF("primary_key", "book", "number")
```

Imports

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Define list of columns:

```scala
val cols = Seq("book", "number")
```

Join as you do right now:

```scala
 val joined = df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), Seq("primary_key"), "fullouter")
```

Define:

```scala
val comp = explode(array(cols.map(c => struct(
  lit(c).alias("diff_column_name"), 
  // Value left
  col(s"l.${c}").cast("string").alias("dataframe1"),  
  // Value right
  col(s"r.${c}").cast("string").alias("dataframe2"),
  // Differs
  not(col(s"l.${c}") <=> col(s"r.${c}")).alias("diff")
)): _*))
```

Select and filter:

```scala
joined
  .withColumn("comp", comp)
  .select($"primary_key", $"comp.*")
  // Filter out mismatches and get rid of obsolete diff
  .where($"diff").drop("diff")
  .orderBy("primary_key").show
// +-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
// |          2|            book|     book2|     book8|
// |          2|          number|         2|         8|
// |          3|          number|         3|         7|
// |          4|            book|     book4|      null|
// |          4|          number|         4|      null|
// |          5|            book|      null|     book5|
// |          5|          number|      null|         5|
// +-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about if the primary_key has multiple columns, as I want to show each of them in the front of result.  Should I simply modified code as:   val columnNames = Seq("key1","key2", "comp.*") joined.withColumn("comp", comp).select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*).where($"diff").drop("diff")

Comment: Do you have the same set of code for python spark ? @hi-zir